# jQuery class selector doesn't work and id selector works only with "body"

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to apply CSS values with jquery but class selector or id selector does not not work for some reason.

[Here is my fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/hY5Dx/63/)

As you can see nothing happens if I use id="kitten".

HTML

```
    <div id="kitten"></div>
```

Script

```
    $(function(){
    var x = 0;
    setInterval(function(){
        x-=1;
        $("kitten").css("background-position", x + "px 0");
    }, 10);
});
```

CSS

```
    html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%;}
    #kitten {
    background-image: url("http://sereedmedia.com/srmwp/wp-content/upload/kitten.jpg");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    }
```

It does not work. However if I use "body" instead of id - all starts to work.

[Fiddle with "body"](http://jsfiddle.net/hY5Dx/64/)

Why I cannot use jQuery id selector or class selector?

Comment: Learn about animate()...and learn about selectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need do:

```
$("#kitten").css("background-position", x + "px 0");
```

Becouse you are not getting the Id selector.

And define a width and height to your div, to show your image like:

```
#kitten {
    background-image: url("http://sereedmedia.com/srmwp/wp-content/uploads/kitten.jpg");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    width: 390px; <----- LIKE this
    height: 200px; <----- LIKE this
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hY5Dx/66/)

Comment: Thank You! Defining div size made the trick! Now it's working perfect!

Answer (score 1):

To reference an id you need to use hash before the id itself, just like you do in css. The correct code would be:

```
$("#kitten").css("background-position", x + "px 0");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $("kitten").css("background-position", x + "px 0");
```

this line is wrong..

this one will do the trick

```
 $("#kitten").css("background-position", x + "px 0");
```

you need to put the right string literals for ID selectors 
check it right [here](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/).

Answer (score 0):

Id selectors are prefixed with `#`:

```
$("#kitten").css("background-position", x + "px 0");
```

A class selector would be prefixed with a `.`, for instance if `kitten` were a class:

```
$(".kitten").css("background-position", x + "px 0");
```

When you use the `body` selector you are using a tag selector which has no prefix.

```
$("input"); //selects all input tags
```

For most basic selectors, just follow CSS selector syntax.

Comment: Neither .kitten nor #kitten is working. I'm trying to understand why "body" still does and what is interrupting the script.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is missing the # which is used for selecting tags by id:

```
$("#kitten")
```