# javascript html placeholder error

Tags: javascript, html, autocomplete

Hello I have the following code on jsfiddle

```
<label for="email">Kerko:</label>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="kerkim" id="input_main">
<label for="name"> Vendi:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control">


var placeholders = ['Elektricist','Hidraulik','Avokat','Doktor','Luleshites'];

(function cycle() {

    var placeholder = placeholders.shift();
    $('input_main').attr('placeholder',placeholder);
    placeholders.push(placeholder);
    setTimeout(cycle,2500);

})();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rcj3thcu/

Can someone help me find out why it is not working?

Also in my localhost both of the inputs start working so it is making me crazy!

Important in my localhost both input fields run
i have
   `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Edit
cache clearing !!! It works!

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery class selector doesn't work and id selector works only with "body"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24442487/jquery-class-selector-doesnt-work-and-id-selector-works-only-with-body)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're trying to reference an id, you should always prefix it with a #:

```
$('#input_main').attr('placeholder',placeholder);
```

Other than that, it's just a matter of configuring JSFiddle properly (include jQuery, for example).

http://jsfiddle.net/rcj3thcu/3/

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the ID-Selector `#` before `input_main`

```
$('#input_main').attr('placeholder',placeholder);
```

Additionally in your jsfiddle there is no jQuery included.