# jQuery Issue cannot retrieve or set attributes, 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes

I have an img element. That image element, on mouse hover, will display a detailed tool tip.

I'm trying to make the img element default start empty null, and feed it the image information from the tooltip on load.

I can't retrieve or assign attributes though using $('idName').attr(a,b);

html and js below:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 text-left"> 
      <h1>Member Equipment</h1>
      <p>-Show member equipment-</p>
      <table class="table">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td><img id="primary" class="img-responsive" src="" alt="Primary"
                onmouseover="document.getElementById('primary_tool_tip').style='display:block'"
                onmouseleave="document.getElementById('primary_tool_tip').style='display:none'">
                <div id="primary_tool_tip" class="bottom" style="display:none">
                    <img id="tooltip_img" src="../images/sword01.jpg" /> 
                    <div id="tooltip_name">Bronze Sword</div>
                    <div id="tooltip_equipslots">Primary, Secondary</div>
                    <div id="tooltip_attributes">STR+2 DEX+2</div>
                    <div id="tooltip_elements">Fire+5</div>
                </div>
            </td>

            <td id="secondary"><img class="img-responsive" src="" alt="Secondary"></td>
            <td id="ranged"><img class="img-responsive" src="" alt="Ranged"></td>
            <td id="ammo"><img class="img-responsive" src="" alt="Ammo"></td>
```

JS

```
alert($("tooltip_img").attr("src"));


function initialize(){
$('primary').prop('src', $('tooltip_img').attr('src') );    
}


window.addEventListener("load", initialize, false );
```

Comment: All of your selectors are in the format of tagName lookups, not classes or ids.  You need to fix your selectors.

Comment: as said by Taplar, fix your selectors, use `#` when finding an element by `id` and `.` when looking for elements with that class class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery class selector doesn't work and id selector works only with "body"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24442487/jquery-class-selector-doesnt-work-and-id-selector-works-only-with-body)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place all of your JavaScript in a JQuery `document.ready()` function so that it doesn't execute until after the DOM has been loaded and is ready to be interacted with.

Then, make sure that you are using correct selectors.

- Tag Name gets elements by the element name.
- Prepending `#` gets elements by ID
- Prepending `.` gets elements by class name

So all together:

```
// The contents of an anonymous function that is passed to JQuery
// won't run until the DOM is parsed and ready to be interacted with.
// This is also known as a "document.ready()" function.
$(function(){
  alert($("#tooltip_img").attr("src"));

  function initialize(){
    $('#primary').prop('src', $('#tooltip_img').attr('src') );    
  }

  window.addEventListener("load", initialize, false );
});
```

Comment: Thanks but this only partially fixed the problem:  $(function(){
  alert($("#tooltip_primary_img").attr("src"));

  function initialize(){
    $("#primaryIcon").attr("src", $("#tooltip_primary_img").attr("src") );   
  }

  window.addEventListener("load", initialize, false );
}); with these additions, at least the alert test at the beginning is properly returning me '../images/sword01.jpg' instead of 'undefined'. The initialize function still fails, and my event works on hovering over 'Primary'(the alt), not the image I want.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `$("#primary")` to target element by id. 
in your case : `$("primary")` will try to find an HTML element named `<primary>`

Comment: Same with tooltip_img

Answer (score 0):

I fiddled around with what Scott gave me made some minor adjustments and everything works now =).

My img is now instantiated from information contained inside my tooltip's bundle of information. Which will eventually be supplied itself from js, and js will supply it through xml externally if things go accordingly.

Thanks for help Scott and company, final refined code below:

Final code

### HTML

```
<div class="col-sm-6 text-left"> 
      <h1>Member Equipment</h1>
      <p>-Show member equipment-</p>
      <table class="table">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
                <img id="primaryIcon" class="img-responsive" src="" alt="Primary"
                onmouseover="document.getElementById('tooltip_primary').style='display:block'"
                onmouseleave="document.getElementById('tooltip_primary').style='display:none'">
                <div id="tooltip_primary" class="standardtooltip">
                    <img id="tooltip_primary_img" src="../images/sword01.jpg" /> 
                    <div id="tooltip_primary_name">Bronze Sword</div>
                    <div id="tooltip_primary_equipslots">Primary, Secondary</div>
                    <div id="tooltip_primary_attributes">STR+2 DEX+2</div>
                    <div id="tooltip_primary_elements">Fire+5</div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <!--
            <td>
                <img id="secondaryIcon" class="img-responsive" src="../images/sword01.jpg" alt="Secondary"
                onmouseover="document.getElementById('tooltip_secondary').style='display:block'"
                onmouseleave="document.getElementById('tooltip_secondary').style='display:none'">
                <div id="tooltip_secondary" class="tooltip" style="display:none">
                    <img id="tooltip_secondary_img" src="../images/sword01.jpg" /> 
                    <div id="tooltip_secondary_name">Bronze Sword</div>
                    <div id="tooltip_secondary_equipslots">Primary, Secondary</div>
                    <div id="tooltip_secondary_attributes">STR+2 DEX+2</div>
                    <div id="tooltip_secondary_elements">Fire+5</div>
                </div>
            </td>
            -->
            <td id="ranged"><img class="img-responsive" src="" alt="Ranged"></td>
            <td id="ammo"><img class="img-responsive" src="" alt="Ammo"></td>
```

### **JS**

```
  $(function(){
    initialize();
  });

  function initialize(){
    document.getElementById("primaryIcon")
        .setAttribute("src", $("#tooltip_primary_img").attr("src"));
        alert('working as intended!');
  }
```